# Adding row to Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am appending the rows to pandas dataframe with 
`key` `name` `value` columns

```
stat_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['key','name','value'])    
names = ["a","b","c"]
cnt = 0
for n in names:
    stat_df.append({'key':cnt,'name':n,'value':0},ignore_index=True)
    cnt += 1
print(stat_df) // Empty dataframe
```

it shows

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [key, name, value]
Index: []
```

Why I can't append the row??

It's might be too simple though, where am I wrong??

Comment: `stat_df = stat_df.append({'key':cnt,'name':n,'value':0},ignore_index=True)`

Comment: oooooooo thank you my super careless mistake... I stuck with this for a while..ashame